# (Java) Changed directory (via bash script) not reflected in folder.listfiles

Tags: java, bash

I run a bash script from my Java program which takes a chunk of data, manipulates it, and splits it up.

It's not a question of whether the bash script works -- I can see the split files in the directory.

Say the original file was "bigFile" in data/

Then

```
    try
    {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash " + SCRIPT_DIR + "/" + SPLIT_SCRIPT_NAME + " " + args[_MESSAGES_PER_UPLOAD_] + " " + args[_MAXIMUM_MESSAGES_PER_FEED_] + " " + (60000*Integer.parseInt(args[_DURATION_BEFORE_EACH_UPLOAD_IN_MINUTES_])/Integer.parseInt(args[_DURATION_OF_EACH_FEED_IN_MILLISECONDS_])));
        proc.waitFor();
    }
    catch(IOException e) { error(e); }

    String fileNames;
    File folder = new File(DATA_DIR);

    File[] filesToUpload = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++i)
        if (filesToUpload[i].isFile()) 
        {
            fileNames = filesToUpload[i].getName();
            System.out.println(fileNames);
        }
```

Will print bigFile, not...

$ ls data/

dataChunk_00000
dataChunk_00001
dataChunk_00002
dataChunk_00003
dataChunk_00004
dataChunk_00005
dataChunk_00006
dataChunk_00007
dataChunk_00008
dataChunk_00009
dataChunk_00010
dataChunk_00011
dataChunk_00012
dataChunk_00013
dataChunk_00014
dataChunk_00015
dataChunk_00016
dataChunk_00017
dataChunk_00018
dataChunk_00019
dataChunk_00020
dataChunk_00021
dataChunk_00022
dataChunk_00023
dataChunk_00024
dataChunk_00025
dataChunk_00026
dataChunk_00027

as it should.  I'm guessing this is a compiler optimization or something.

Edit: If somebody could explain to me why proc.waitFor() isn't working and/or a better way to solve this, I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: Could you share the content of your bash script? Or at least explain what it is doing step-by-step?

Comment: As an aside, you should use `Runtime.exec(String[])` instead of `.exec(String)` like you're doing here, for all but the absolute *simplest* things. `Runtime.exec()` is not a shell or parser and doesn't honor quoting or escaping.  Providing all your arguments in a single string can often lead to unexpected treatment of arguments because `exec(String)` blindly splits on spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this is not compiler optimization or anything like that.

Its because you are invoking your script with a "bash" in front of it . This causes the process to fork -- so your bash command returns successfully immediately , but your script continues to run in the background and terminate.

The proc.waitFor() has nothing to wait for, the rest of the java program executes before your file has been "split".

Comment: I see.  Is there a better workaround to this other than using Thread.sleep()?

Comment: You could get rid of the "bash" and let the script execute directly ( so it doesn't spawn a new process ).

Comment: It gives me !-- Cannot run program "scripts/splitAndEnumerate.sh": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied

Comment: chmod +x on scripts/splitAndEnumerate.sh

Comment: Erm, simple fix... chmod.  Thanks, Kal.

Comment: I'd be surprised if chmod works ;-) Going to work now, will reply and explain if stil unanswered until evening.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the directory with java.
If you want to "simulate" it, all you need to do is set the property "user.dir".

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your bash script is performing actions asynchronously from its own process/thread. This means that the script finishes executing before the work is complete. This would still pass the waitFor() check and continue executing the code.

EDIT:
Kal's answer explains this more clearly, and it was posted first. The problem is the fact that you use the bash command to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your arguments aren't all passed to your script.

Put all your arguments in an ArrayList instance, pass the instance to the ProcessBuilder, then call the `start` method on the builder instance, which returns the proc on which you call `waitFor`.

Here's sample Scala code to show what I mean (I can port it to Java if you're really interested ;-):

```
import java.lang.{ Process => JProcess, ProcessBuilder => JProcessBuilder }
import java.util.{ArrayList => JArrayList, List => JList, Map => JMap}
import java.io.{InputStreamReader, BufferedReader}

def call(args: String*) = {
    val command: JList[String] = new JArrayList[String]()

    args.foreach {arg =>
      command.add(arg)
    }

    //log.debug("argument list: %s", command.toString)

    val builder = new JProcessBuilder(command)

    val proc: JProcess = builder.start()
    proc.waitFor()

    val read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    val sb: StringBuffer = new StringBuffer()
    while(read.ready()) {
      sb.append(read.readLine)
    }

    // sb now has the output of the called process...

    val exitValue: Int = proc.exitValue

    // http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/11/28/crash-boom-too-many-open-files/
    read.close
    proc.destroy

    (exitValue, sb.toString) // return it
}
```

Example call in REPL:

```
scala> call("date")
res156: (Int, java.lang.String) = (0,Mon 18 Jul 2011 22:29:58 BST)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of wrong assumptions with this program:

1. Every time you do 'exec' you fork a new process, with its own environment, current directory, etc. Any change of the current directory would have been local to that process and will not affect the parent (your Java process). In other words, there is no way to change the current path of an application using a command in a sub-process, there is no Java API for that either - if you really need this, you have to use native call.
2. The 'cd' command on Unix is a real command, you do not need the shell in order to run it (unlike Windows).
3. When you fork a process, you need to make sure that you drain the stdout and stderr, or it is going to block when the OS buffer gets full (see next)
4. Process.waitFor() works. Always.

A better way to approach the problem is to read carefully the File API and as much as possible work with absolute paths. The 'current directory' is something very usefull when you are in shell, but for applications it ends up being more confusing, so the sooner you resolve it to absolute path - the better.